# OrientDB - ensure consistent state

Tags: java, orientdb

I am not quite sure how to ask this question but I hope you get my drift...

I am using OrientDB as an embedded database that is used by a single application. I would like to ensure that should this application crash, the database is always in a consistent state so that my application can be started again without having to perform an maintenance on the database or loosing any data.

Ie so when I change the database and get a success message, I know that the changes have been written.

Is this support by OrientDB, if so, what is the option to enable?

(P.S. if I knew what the general accepted term for this kind of setup is called, I could search myself...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrientDB uses some kind of rollback journal which means that by default it logs all operations are performed with data stored on disk and put them into append only log. Records of this log are cached and flushed every second. If application crashes WAL (write ahead)/operation log will be read and all operations will be applied once again. Also WAL has notion of transactions which means that if transaction will not be finished at the time of crash all applied changes will be rolled back. So you can be sure about following in OrientDB:

1. All data the were written before one second interval before crash will be restored.
2. All data are written inside of transaction will be in consistent state.
3. You can lost part of the data in last one second interval.

Interval of flushes of WAL cache can be changed but it may lead to performance slowdown.